# How to override Shake configuration on the command-line

Tags: shake-build-system

I maintain small configuration files per project read via `usingConfigFile`. I'd like to be able to override any of those settings on the command line. It seems using `shakeArgsWith` (rather than `shakeArgs`) is the first step on the way but I don't see an obvious way to wire that through to the values produced by `getConfig`. Is there a standard approach for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a standard approach, but I know several larger build systems have invented something. A combination of `shakeArgsWith`, `readConfigFile` and `usingConfig` should do it. Something like (untested):

```
main = shakeArgsWith shakeOptions [] $ \_ args -> return $ Just $ do
    file <- readConfigFile "myfile.cfg"
    usingConfig $ Map.union (argsToSettings args) file
    myNormalRules
```

Where `argsToSettings` is some function that parses your arguments and turns them into settings - e.g. breaking on the first `=` symbol or similar.